# We intend to support the iPhone 5, do we need to upgrade Xcode to v4.5 and use the iOS 6 SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk

We want to update our game to support the iPhone 5.
Do we need to upgrade Xcode to v4.5 and use the iOS 6 SDK??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[edit]Apple is now explicitly rejecting applications submitted with the iOS 5.x SDK and iPhone 5 default images, saying "Your app contains a launch image with a size modifier that is only supported for apps built with the iOS 6.0 SDK or later."

Old answer :
Yes you can use Xcode 4.4 or below to support iPhone 5.

The iOS (6) will run an app in letterbox mode if there is not a 640x1136 splashscreen image in your resources. The image must be called Default-568h@2x.png (if your splashscreen is Default.png in your Info.plist).

So just add this image on your Xcode project whatever version it is, and the app will run in full screen mode.

This being said, there are chances that Apple will not let you install an app compiled with Xcode 4.4 or below on an iOS 6 device (and of course no iPhone 5 simulator for Xcode 4.4 and below). [edit] As told in the comments, yes, you can install on an iPhone 5 / iOS6 with Xcode4.4.

Comment: Just tried and it works : we can install apps on iPhone5 (iOS6) with Xcode 4.4.

Answer (score 2):

All apps created with older SDK works perfectly on newer iOS versions, so iPhone 5 should also run every existing app without any problem, so you don't need to use the iOS 6.0 SDK to support iPhone 5.

Comment: Well, not *all*, but almost. Probably something like 99%.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to ask to support iOS 5. If that is the case then you really do not need to upgrade your Xcode version. YOu can use iOS SDK 5.0 or iOS SDK 5.1 which contains Xcode version 4.2 and 4.3.

You really do not need to use iOS SDK 6.0 beta. I hope this may help you.

Comment: Please don't mind marking the answer right if that solves your purpose. :)

Comment: Thanks for your replay.
I means support iPhone 5(1136*640）

Comment: Oh! You are really sure iPhone 5 is released?. Get me one if that is released :).

Answer (score 0):

All the information about iOS 6 are under NDA, and the iPhone 5 is not even announced.

But there are rumors, that the iPhone 5 will have a screen resolution of 1136*640. There are [hacks for Xcode 4.4.1](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/08/a-taller-iphone-is-a-giraffe/) out there that make it possible to create that screen resolution in the iPhone simulator. So, I think that would be a viable way for testing the rumored new resolution.

Regarding iOS 6: if you are a paying iOS developer, you can download iOS 6 to test your app against it (We don't talk about products under NDA here).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this receipt http://0xced.blogspot.co.at/2012/08/prepare-your-apps-for-new-iphone.html for start iOS Simulator (iOS 5 only) with new screen size.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, You need to update your Xcode to build for iPhone5. Do the following steps for this:

- Download Xcode 4.5 with iOS 5.1 SDK.
- Build your apps with Xcode 4.5.